# `ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete` using the `TABLE` operator on a method over dblink

Tags: sql, oracle, dblink

I am trying to run the following

```sql
SELECT SOME_FIELD
FROM TABLE( REMOTE_SCHEMA.SOME_PACKAGE.SOME_METHOD@SOME_DBLINK('my-input') )
```

but it fails with `ORA-21700: object does not exist or is marked for delete`

the db version on both sides is `Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production Version 19.17.0.0.0`

Is this possible at all? Any work-arounds to get the data from pipelined view to the other DB?

Comment: Does your database link connect user have permissions to execute that package? Also I haven't tried referring to remote SQL collection types in recent versions, but that could be a source of trouble if the local database can't type it correctly.

Comment: yes, we have the permission and can execute that query on the remote db